# How to perform differential sync at Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I sync values from database to local collections as source values and perform operations on these docs subsequently I push updated docs back to the corresponding db table, at success of push I want to pull only those docs from updated database that are not present at local collection of my device.
I could have used sync time stamp but in some peculiar situation either some docs get duplicated or got missing at my device.
I must also bring to notice that the local database also gets augmented while I perform operations at the device.

Answer (score 1):

JSON Store is what you need in this case. More details here -

[JSONStore](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/data/jsonstore/jsonstore-javascript-api/)